# Enable HDMI output on 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I've installed Ubuntu for the first time a few days ago (20.04.1 LTS). My current concern is that `xrandr`/`arandr` as well as the `gnome-control-center` do not show my second monitor plugged in via HDMI. Below are a few information and a screenshot from my current system:

[image]

`inxi`:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce MX350] driver: nvidia v: 450.80.02 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: fbdev,nvidia unloaded: modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

`xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

I am running Ubuntu on Intel i7-1165G7 and a NVIDIA GeForce MX350 graphics card. On `arandr`, the `Outputs` tab only contains a single dropdown field with the "default" screen (even though I would have expected a different name, like "eDP-1"). Also, the message

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Is something I haven't seen on my previous Debian installation on an older laptop. Does this have something to do with my problem? Is it possible to somehow enable the HDMI output on my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and have found a cure. My latptop has an Intel i7-1165G7 and an nvidia MX450 graphics card. As in a discussion with Nvidia Support, I realised my laptop did not have any HDMI port available on the nvidia GPU. The HDMI port is driven by the intel graphics rather than the nvidia graphics card. Ubuntu 20.04.1 is based on the kernel series 5.4. However kernel 5.4 does not support Intel Gen12 Tiger Lake graphics. Then I upgraded my Ubuntu kernel from 5.4 to 5.8.0. It worked.

Here is the link to ubuntu kernel .deb files [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/) and a guide on how to upgrade the kernel https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this was indeed the reason. I had to adjust the steps a bit because I still had secure boot enabled that doesn't work with UEFI and unsigned kernels. Also, I had to adjust the grub.cfg in the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub` directory as well since the normal kernel installation does not work on EFI partitions.

Comment: It should be noted that it is probably recommendable to search for linux images in the packate manager first (e.g. via `apt-cache`) since a signed kernel 5.8.0 was also available there. Removed the unsigned versions now and installed it from the package manager directly. Works like a charm.